# With Python's attrs, is it possible to remove leading underscores from the generated __repr__

Tags: python-attrs

With my project that uses attrs, I'm defining some fields with a leading underscore so that I can make a property with the same name minus the leading underscore. I'm doing this because I'm adding some simple logic to the setter method for when the value get's set (very important).

I was wondering if there is a way I could remove the leading underscores from the `__repr__`.

I couldn't find anything about this after some google searching, so I figure there might be a way attrs helps you handle data being set? I'm not sure though.

If anyone could recommend me some solutions or ways they'd tackle this problem, I'd appreciate it very much!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the *name* of fields is not supported unfortunately. You can pass a callable for attr.ib/attrs.field’s *repr*, but that only affects the value.